# Joint PDF question about interrelated variables

Tags: statistics

I am trying to find the joint PDF $f_{U,V}$ of the random variables U and V. 
Let the random variables U and V be defined as follows...
$$U = X + Y$$
$$V = Y + Z$$
where X, Y, and Z are random variables with known PDFs for every joint and conditional of X, Y, and Z.

To get $f_{U,V}$, we may want to first find $F_{U,V}$...

$$F_{U,V} = \mathbb P(U \le u_0, V \le v_0)$$
$$= \mathbb P(X + Y \le u_0, Y + Z \le v_0)$$
$$= \mathbb P(X \le u_0 - Y, Y \le v_0 - Z)$$
$$= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{v_0-z} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{u_0-y} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$

At this point, we are left with a $z$ term hanging. What do we do now?

Another question:
Eventually we will need to find $f_{U,V}(u_0, v_0)$ from $F_{U,V}(u_0, v_0)$. We know that...
$$f_{U,V}(u_0, v_0) = \frac {\partial^2F_{U,V}(u_0, v_0)}{\partial u_0 \, \partial v_0}$$

But how do we write the answer in terms of some joint PDF of $X, Y,$ and/or $Z$?

Thanks for the help!

---

EDIT:

X, Y, and Z are not independent.

I think I may have found the solution. Please kindly offer your comments.

We know that a marginal density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is equal to...
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) \, dz$$
Then we can say that...
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{v_0-z} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{u_0-y} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$
$$= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{v_0-z} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{u_0-y} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) \, dz \, dx \, dy$$
And interchanging the order of integration...
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{v_0-z} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{u_0-y} f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) \, dx \, dy \, dz$$

Now how do we solve this below?
$$f_{U,V}(u_0, v_0) = \frac {\partial^2\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{v_0-z} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{u_0-y} f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) \, dx \, dy \, dz}{\partial u_0 \, \partial v_0}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have three random variables on one side.  Take care of all of them. $$\begin{align}F_{U,V}(u,v)&=\iiint_{ (x,y,z):x+y\leq u,y+z\leq v}f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)~\mathrm d(x,y,z)\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{u-y}\int_{-\infty}^{v-y}~f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\mathrm d z~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y\\[3ex] f_{U,V}(u,v)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y,Z}(u-y,y,v-y)~\left\lVert\dfrac{\partial\langle u-y,v-y\rangle}{\partial \langle u,v\rangle}\right\rVert~\mathrm d y\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y,Z}(u-y,y,v-y)~\mathrm d y\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, that seems to match with my proposed solution

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that $X$, $Y$,and $Z$ are independent random variables.

Then you find first
$$P(V<v|Y=y) = P(X< v- y) = F_X(v-y).$$
Then,
$$f_{V|Y}(v,y) = f_{X}(v-y).$$

Similarly,
$$f_{U|Y}(u,y) = f_{Z}(u-y).$$

Finally, use the law of conditional probability to say that
$$f_{U,V,Y}(u,v,y)= f_{U|Y}(u,y)f_{V|Y}(y,v)f_Y(y);$$
from which you find your joint via marginalization:

$$f_{U,V} =\int f_{U,V,Y}(u,v,y) \mathrm d y.$$

Comment: Thank you for the help, but we cannot assume independence in this particular problem